# Move hard disk from one Lenovo computer to another? Is it likely to work?

Tags: 12.04, lenovo, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad x220 and have ordered a Lenovo T430s. Ideally I'd like to move the SSD (running 12.04) from the x220 to the new machine, rather than installing the OS on the new one and updating apps and restoring Home directory. Is it likely to work if I just put the current drive in the new machine?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is very likely to work. Linux is much more... transferrable then, say, Windows.

I have an HDD which migrated from an Atom-based netbook to a quad-core desktop to another laptop and it booted perfectly in all those machines.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this works much better than on Windows. I move my SSD between my work laptop (Dell) and my home computer on an everyday basis.

Depending on which graphics hardware the machines have (which on Lenovos is probably going to be Intel) you may have to reconfigure a bit (mostly if nvidia is involved).

Comment: Both machines have Intel graphics. I deliberately didn't get the Nvidia option on the new one...